# trying to add text before and after some text

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I tried the following commands:

1. Running the line below gives the output text mentioned.

   ```sh
   cat $tmp_list_address | sort | uniq | sed 's/^/address=\//;s/$/\/192.168.1.1/' > $tmp_list_final
   ```
2. Running the line below gives the output text mentioned.

   ```sh
   sed -i 's/.*/address=&\/192.168.1.1/' $tmp_list_address
   ```
3. I even tried doing things separately. The following adds the `address=` part. but when it tries to add the IP at the end, it changes to the output text below.

   ```sh
   sed -i 's/^/address=/' $tmp_list_address
   sed -i 's/$/$pixelserv_ip/' $tmp_list_ip
   ```

The original list is the one I am trying to get, where blanks and white spaces are also being saved, and I am removing them before trying to add text.

```sh
curl -s http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt | grep -v "#" | sed '/^$/d' | sed 's/\ /\\ /g' | awk '{print $3}' | grep -v '^\\' | grep -v '\\$' | sort >> $tmp_list

sed -i 's/^ *//; s/ *$//; /^$/d' $tmp_list
```

Desired output:

```sh
address=/0koryu0.easter.ne.jp/0.0.0.0
address=/109-204-26-16.netconnexion.managedbroadband.co.uk/0.0.0.0
address=/11.lamarianella.info/0.0.0.0
```

Note: `0.0.0.0` can be also some other IP address such as `192.168.1.1`.

Input text:

```sh
0koryu0.easter.ne.jp
109-204-26-16.netconnexion.managedbroadband.co.uk
11.lamarianella.info
1866809.securefastserver.com
2amsports.com
3.bluepointmortgage.com
```

Output text:

```sh
/10.0.0.1109-204-26-16.netconnexion.managedbroadband.co.uk
/10.0.0.111.lamarianella.info
/10.0.0.11866809.securefastserver.com
/10.0.0.12amsports.com
/10.0.0.13.bluepointmortgage.com
```

Comment: Your question isn't at all clear to me, but you seem to have at least two classic issues (1) trying to use `/` in your pattern or replacement text when sed is already using it as a delimiter: here you need to either escape it `\/` or switch to a different delimiter e.g. `'s;^;address=/;'` (2) expecting variable expansion to occur within single quotes `'s/$/$pixelserv_ip/'` (switch to double quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Use sed grouping.

```
curl -s http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt | sed 's#^\([0-9.]*\)  \([a-z0-9.]*\)#address=/\2/0.0.0.0#'
```